# warning: "statement seems to have no effect"

Tags: python, python-3.x

PyCharm is highlighting my code in yellow and giving a warning. On hover, it says:

> statement seems to have no effect

Can somebody please explain what this means?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code here

Comment: Always show code as ... code. In this case there's no need to copy this code, but if there was, nobody would want to waste their time playing scribe.

Comment: ```=``` and ```==``` are different. The ```==``` are comparisons signs which will return either True or False. Change that to  a single ```=```

Answer (score 3):

You need a single equals sign `=` to assign a value to `punctuacion`:

```
punctuacion = punctuacion + 10
```

In this case, it'd be even better to use a compound assignment operator, like `punctuation

```
punctuacion += 10
```

As is, the `==` is the equality operator, which just evaluates to an unused value (either `True` or `False`). That's useless, hence the warning, the IDE suspects you made a mistake like this.